# Ionic v5 - Ion-slide how to change pagination position

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ion-slides, ionslider

I need help!

I am trying to change the position of the ion-slide pagination. I know I can change to the .swiper-pagination class. However, I can only put .swiper-pagination in global.css. But this brings a huge problem, all the slides on the other pages have inherited this configuration and I just want to change it on one page.

How do I set .swiper-pagination of the component’s css page?

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido!

I managed to put the cosigo below in the component's css.

tab1.css

```
.swiper-slide, .swiper-pagination {
    bottom: -20px! important;
}
```